# Ubuntu 22.10 kernel crashes on Lenovo ThinkPad P1 Gen 4

Tags: kernel, lenovo, crash, thinkpad

After upgrade  from version 22.04 to version 22.10 the kernel started to crash. It happens each time after booting up the computer and logging in. Doesn't happen in single user mode. I updated BIOS to the latest version. Kernel is 5.0-19-23-generic #24-ubuntu. It seems it’s related with getting power supply property.

I can't report the crash using Ubuntu's tools as the laptop is dead after it happens.

[kernel crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d11ln.jpg)

Comment: What kernel are you running? On startup from grub in advance menu choose an older kernel if you have one and see if machine starts.

Comment: Yes,  older kernel works fine. Later I can provide its version.

Answer (score 0):

i follow your question because it is similar with mine [Ubuntu 22.04 not booting and fan speed is fast](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1438025/ubuntu-22-04-not-booting-and-fan-speed-is-fast)

I suggest you to upgrading kernel with Mainline Kernel Installer and install the latests kernel (I solved with kernel 6.0.6).

I wish help you and still follow your question.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to uninstall any nvidia binary *before* upgrading. Now, since it seems to work on single user mode, try uninstall any nvidia package and see it it boots again. Then try to reinstall the correct nvidia drivers. Sometimes during upgrade, those proprietary drivers get in the way.

Comment: This is not necessary and may cause problems with the upgrade. The machine may not even have a working screen to be able to do the upgrade without the correct video driver.

Comment: My experience is the opposite. I resolved every failed upgrade with an nvidia binary installed uninstalling, finishing the upgrade, reinstalling the driver. Sometimes the same driver used in the upgrade did not work anymore and uninstalling it is the best way to test other drivers versions to get the working one. Sometimes I have to go with the Noveau one, the free version that is disabled when the proprietary drivers are installed, or either downgrade the kernel version. I did that with dozens of install so my experience may be not good enough for a statistic but good enough to report it.

Comment: The problem is most probably caused by power supply handling- take a look at attachments. Stack trace is similar each crash. The system works fine with older kernel.