# Ubuntu 22.04 not booting and fan speed is fast

Tags: boot, kernel, 22.04, thinkpad, fan

On my thinkpad T14 Gen 2 which I purchased on July 2022 I have installed Ubuntu 22.04. Recently the fan speed runs very fast and System Monitor does not show the CPU is working hard. I have tied to fix it with this guide on reddit. https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/wrvsm2/laptops_fan_stops_working_after_suspend_ubuntu/

When I restarted my laptop it does non boot.

I have used a Live USB and removed kernel 5.17 and restarted the laptop, but it often keeps crashing. Although I have launched recovery mode to fix a damaged package (dpkg command) the problem keeps repeating itself.

Edit

I have already done a test with Boot Repair with this result: http://sprunge.us/wKshGy

Comment: Is this a Dell machine? Kernel 5.17 has been the cause of may issues recently. Most have been fixed by running kernel 5.15 What kernel are you running now?

Comment: I have already written on: this is a Thinkpad, Lenovo, T14 Gen 2.

Comment: The kernel that run now is 5.15 because i removed 5.17. The problem still continue anyway.

Comment: OK lets try one more time. What do you mean by crashing? Does it not boot? Does it boot and you login and it crashes? Please add some more detail. From your question "Although I have launched recovery mode to fix a damaged package (dpkg command) the problem keeps repeating itself." Please explain what this means. What damaged package. Did the issues start after you did this "fix"?

Comment: Sorry David.

When I turned on my laptop, it blocked on loading ubuntu 22.04. Sometimes it's block when logo Lenovo appears, sometimes it blocks after logo lenovo while ubuntu loading. 

When you turn on laptop you can go into GRUB (press ESC on starting laptop) and appears a list of kernel/ubuntu 22.04 you can choose. There is also ubuntu 22.04 kernel 5.15 Recovery Mode.

Comment: In recovery mode there is a list of command you can execute. I execute dpkg command for fix damaged package and after a command for control File System. The problem persist anyway and I didn't fix it.

Comment: OK you mean freezes.

Comment: Boot into recovery mode, in the final recovery mode menu; run `fsck` and `activate network` options (tell if either fails!) and then `drop to root prompt`. At the root prompt first do `apt update && apt upgrade`... then if no errors there;  examine the files in `/var/log/`  (for .gz files use `zcat file.gz | less`) and also `journalctl --system --until=...` with a relevant date might be helpful; look for failures, errors and similar... Add any findings above.

Comment: Hello Hannu, 

I have booted into recovery mode and after fsck this is the result

"/lib/recovery-mode/recovery-menu: line 80: /etc/default/rcS: No such file or directory
fsck from util-linux 2.37.2
/dev/nvme0n1p3 is mounted.
e2fsck: Cannot Continue, aborting"

Comment: After activate network and run "apt update && apt upgrade" I continue and resume but when i reboot the system this still freeze on booting. 
How I insert date in journal command?

Comment: I check into the grub various kernel. 

kernel 5.15.0-52-generic freeze at booting
kernel 5.15.0-53-generic  freeze at booting
Kernel 5.17.0-1020-oem works!

But the problem with fan speed persists!

Comment: Apparently SOLVED!

After running into kernel 5.17 I have launched mainline from terminal and installed the latest kernel version: 6.0.6-060006-generic. 

After selected this kernel at starting bootloader i reboot the system and now it works fine! Fan speed is good, laptop is not hot and apparently all works fine. 

Later I will try touchpad (because this had problem I saw in another thread). 

Thanks to Hannu and David for your helps.